# error TS2559: Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

This is my code but, I'm getting the same result. how can I fix this for it to work?

error TS2559: Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-send-mail',
  templateUrl: './send-mail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./send-mail.component.css']
})
export class SendMailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http:  HttpClient) { }

  sendEmail() {

    const url = `https://your-cloud-function-url/function`;
    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

    params.set('to', 'email');
    params.set('from', 'email@website.com');
    params.set('subject', 'test-email');
    params.set('content', 'Hello World');

    return this.http.post(url, params, headers)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then( res => {
                      console.log(res);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                      console.log(err);
                    });

  }
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter should be the request options object, which includes the headers, not just the headers. Try changing it to `this.http.post(url, params, { headers })` instead

Comment: check my answer, it should solve your issue. Looks like you have mixed up between the old and new httpclient modules

Answer (score 3):

As you are using the new `HttpClient`from `'@angular/common/http';` (introduced in Angular 4) along with the `HttpClientModule` to make the POST call, hence you should use 
`HttpHeaders` instead of `Headers` from `'@angular/http';` . You also need to pass the the headers as an Object like `{headers}`.

Here is the modified code -

```
sendEmail() {

    const url = `https://your-cloud-function-url/function`;
    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

    params.set('to', 'email');
    params.set('from', 'email@website.com');
    params.set('subject', 'test-email');
    params.set('content', 'Hello World');

    return this.http.post(url, params, {headers})
                    .toPromise()
                    .then( res => {
                      console.log(res);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                      console.log(err);
                    });

  }
```