# Angular "error TS2559: Type 'string' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders "

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code trying to make an angular app from the ng new template. I'm following this as a guide. https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express

When googling I found this on the typescript github as the cloest thing to my issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24835

Also while making this question I came across this one but I don't think the solution written would solve my problem. [error TS2559: Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224476/error-ts2559-type-headers-has-no-properties-in-common-with-type-requestoptio)

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export interface Data {
data: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  title = 'My Star Database';

  Character(name: string) 
  {
  }
  sendCharacter(name: string): Observable<Data> {
          return this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/', name);
                  }
                  getCharacterData(name: string): Observable<Data> {
                          var data =  this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/', name);
                          console.log(data);
                          }

  }
```

**error**

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(24,71): error TS2559: Type 'string' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
src/app/app.component.ts(26,37): error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
src/app/app.component.ts(27,78): error TS2559: Type 'string' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
```

**side note**
Also I'd like to add that in the code I added the export interface and changed  to  in the get request because I was getting an error over the get request having a string return type. This is my first experience writing in typescript and i have to say between that error (which I made go away) and the one you see above I don't feel typescript really deserves its name. I wish the angular devs stuck with javascript. Sorry for the rant I'm very frustrated over this language and I'm not new to programming. I love the three Cs and Python.

**Update
app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export interface Data {
data: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  title = 'My Star Database';

  Character(name: string) 
  {
  }
  sendCharacter(name: string): Observable<Data> {
          return this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/?name='+ name);
                  }
                  getCharacterData(name: string): {
                           data =  this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/?name='+ name);
                          console.log(data);
                          }

  }
```

**error** 
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(27,7): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(28,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(31,3): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: I guess you are passing wrong header in `http.get()`

Comment: You cannot have `@Component` and `@Injectable` on same class

Comment: Also `getCharacterData` method should return instance of `Observable` as its return type is `Observable`. If you do not want to return anything then remove its return type.

Comment: httpClient get does not accept a body but accepts headers and you are passing name as headers hence the error

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Thanks I removed that.

Comment: @CruelEngine I hope you're not implying that variable data can't be transferred to nodejs the way I have it written with the module. That would defeat the purpose of this whole thing.

Comment: @codehelp4 variable data can be passed but as query params and not the way you're trying .

Comment: @CruelEngine Oh ok thanks. I've been following that page I linked to above which only used the query params style when dealing with nodejs code so I thought that style only applied to nodejs code but I'll try to imitate it in angular code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 1 is due to passing invalid parameters in *http.get* function. The second parameter for *http.get* is supposed to be headers. If you want to pass parameter in get, include it  as a URL parameter.

```
return this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/?name='+name);
```

Error 2 is because you are not returning anything from *getCharacterData()* function. Either remove the return option i.e.

```
getCharacterData(name: string) {
    var data =  this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/?name='+name);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Or return the data,

```
getCharacterData(name: string): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/?name='+name);
}
```

Error 3 is a duplicate of error 1

Comment: Thanks I made those fixes but now I get this error. `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(27,7): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(28,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(31,3): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.` I'll update my question with the changes.

Comment: Simple syntax errors : `getCharacterData(name: string) {var data =  this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/?name='+ name);
console.log(data); }`

Comment: No angular doesn't like adding var. (I know weird) Here's the error I get when I do that. `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(26,5): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(28,6): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(30,3): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.` One of the many annoyances I've had making this thing with angular.

Comment: In that case, `getCharacterData(name: string) { console.log(this.http.get<Data>('http://localhost:8000/api/character/?name='+ name)) }`

Comment: Adding var doesn't make any error. Tried the whole snippet myself.

Comment: My apologies pasting your code with the var worked. It must've been more than just the var that I had wrong. Odd I've had issues using var before with angular. Anyway Thanks. I'll mark this. :)